# Navigation bar not appearing

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Can someone help me with this? :(

The navigation bar is not appearing. This is presented by a rootViewController.

[image]

Comment: You are Trying to show Navigation bar on a root controller itself , If you navigate to another controller from this root navBar will Appear, if you want o show navBar in your current root either make a newVc that will be used as root between NavController and your current Root

Comment: @iOSGeek Incorrect. A single view controller in a navigation controller will show the navigation bar. You do not need another view controller.

Comment: So, what should I really do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not posted any code still guessing.

Just taking `UINavigationController` in storyboad doesn't means that it will appear by default.

You are just presenting view controller. You need to embed in navigation controller or give storyboard identifier to navigation controller and present that.

Example :

```
    let yourviewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVCIdentifer")

    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourviewController)

    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I just embbed the ViewController using Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Comment: @Creign  Not this way bro.  create programmatically `UINavigationController(rootViewController: yourVCObjcect)` and present that

Comment: I don't get it. Is this an extension? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Creign Edited answer pls check now